# Gathering search results from a multi-model query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, elasticsearch, controller, enumerable

I'm currently indexing search queries using the searchkick gem. It should also be noted that I'm searching across two models, `Artists` and `Albums`. In my `search_controller` I have 3 instance variables, first being `@results` for returning all results across the two models for my `autocomplete` (used elsewhere):

```
@results = Artist.search(params[:query], index_name: [Artist.searchkick_index.name, Album.searchkick_index.name], fields: [{ name: :word_start }], limit: 10)
```

Then there  are my `@artists/@albums` instance variables.

```
@artists = @results.select { |result| result.class.name == "Artist" }
@albums = @results.select { |result| result.class.name == "Album" }
```

I split these results up so that I can group artists and albums in my index view as so:

```
<h1>Search Results</h1>

<div class="artist-results">
  <h2>Artists</h2>

  <% @artists.each do |artist| %>
    <%= link_to artist.name, artist_path(artist) %>
  <% end %>
</div>

<div class="album-results">
  <h2>Albums</h2>

  <% @albums.each do |album| %>
    <%= link_to album.name, album_path(album) %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

The one main concern I have with my search controller code is that I'm performing 2 almost identical enumerables. I could be wrong but something tells me that I shouldn't do this. Is there a more performant solution to what I'm doing? Am I on the right track with this?

**Complete Controller Code**

```
class SearchController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :set_results

  def index
  end

  def autocomplete
    render json: @results
  end

  private
    def set_results
      @results = Artist.search(params[:query], index_name: [Artist.searchkick_index.name, Album.searchkick_index.name], fields: [{ name: :word_start }], limit: 10)
      @artists = @results.select { |result| result.class.name == "Artist" }
      @albums = @results.select { |result| result.class.name == "Album" }
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure it's more performant.  But you could Use [group by](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by).

```
results = Artist.search(params[:query], index_name: [Artist.searchkick_index.name, Album.searchkick_index.name], fields: [{ name: :word_start }], limit: 10)
@grouped_results = results.group_by{|x| x.class.name }
```

Then

```
<h1>Search Results</h1>

<% @grouped_results.each do |class_name, results| %>
  <div class="<%= class_name.downcase %>-results">
    <h2><%= class_name.pluralize %></h2>

    <% results.each do |result| %>
      <%= link_to result %>
    <% end %>    
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks. I think you're missing a double quote at the end of the class declaration.

Comment: No problem. Found a mistake on my end. Forgot to add the first parameter to my `link_to`'s. So basically `<%= link_to result %>` should've read as `<%= link_to result.name, result %>`. That's my bad for not writing it out fully in my original question.

Comment: While on the topic had one question. How does Rails know how to correctly link to the correct page without a designated helper like `artist_path(artist)` or writing it longhand: `{ controller: artist, id: artist }`?

Comment: Magic...it makes assumptions.  It'll go to [url_for](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/UrlFor.html#method-i-url_for) which will fall down to and essentially will assume you've followed rails' conventions as I understand it.  So artists will be under `artist_path(artist)`

Comment: Magical it is. Thanks. If I could trouble you for one additional question. Say that album had an attribute called `title` instead of `name` (playing devil's advocate here). Would you have to write some sort've conditional that checks the `class_name` within the each block to appropriately display the correct text? Also, +1 for you're additional help.

Comment: You could do that.  Or you could define a method in album `def name; title; end` that simply defines name and returns title.

Comment: Wow I never thought of that approach. Thanks again for your help.